# Call code behind c# function from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, entity-framework

I know this has been asked, but none of the numerous answers fit with my situation.  So I will humbly ask if someone can walk me through this again gently.

Environment:  .Net 4 web app using c#, javascript, jquery, sql server, and entity framework.

Question:  I need to be able to allow a user to "quick add" a value into a table that is bound to a drop down box without losing values a user has already entered onto current page.  I don't care if I have to do a postback or use jquery or use ajax, etc.  I need the functionality first - prettiness later ... the scenario is described below if you care to keep reading.  With all that being said, I would love for this to be smooth and not "clunky" for the user.

Scenario:
I have a page where the user is able to enter many pieces of information into textboxes, static drop down boxes, and drop down boxes that are bound to other tables that will all get combined and inserted into one table.  Well, it never fails, a user could be filling in the page and when they get to one of the table bound drop down boxes - a value is missing or they haven't added something item yet.  I would like to add a button or link or something next to that drop down box that would allow the user to "quick add" an item to the table that fills that drop down box and then refresh the drop down box so they can choose that new value from the list ... all while not losing the other data on the screen they already entered.

What I've tried: 
-Tried WebMethod option. Currently, this web page calls some custom "bind" methods in the code behind to fill drop down boxes so they are not filled directly from objects from entity framework.  So that means using a static method will not work for a solution because part of the static function would need to call the bind method to refresh the drop down box with the newly inserted values.

-Tried PageMethod option.  Some of the other samples used Page Method settings, but my site uses master and content pages and the posts seem to state that the page method route was not going to work.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `UpdatePanel` to the page.  The update panel should wrap the drop down to be added, as well as the textbox/button for adding a new entry to that drop down.  You would want to have a different UpdatePanel for each dropdown/button pair, if applicable.

When they click the button inside of the update panel you can read the textbox, add an extra item to the drop down, and send an update to the database.  (I'd manually add the new value to the drop down rather than updating the database and re-binding, if possible, but it may not be.)

The magic of UpdatePanels will make sure that this is all asynchronous and so doesn't disturb the user working on the page.

Comment: I like that ... one step further - What if I use a dialog or popup of some sort that "pops up" a modal dialog with one textbox where you enter the name (the key for the table in question is only "name") ... that is usually jquery or something javascript ... would it be best to put that name in a hidden field and reference it from some code behind function?  Or just have a textbox somewhere on the form in a "quick add area" so to speak and use an asp:button click event and handle everything there ... with an updatepanel ...?

Comment: I would probably have the textbox/button in a div that's hidden, and then have a link that, when clicked, showed the div.  If someone were suitably motivated they could make that div a floating modal popup type of thing.  At that point it's all fancy javascript on the client side that doesn't change the underlying strategy here.  Keep in mind it's important for this floating div to be defined inside of the update panel, and that things that don't need to be "inside" of the update panel aren't it's children.

Comment: ok - makes sense - function first .. flash later ..

As far as adding item to drop down first or db first .. I have to add it to the db first so when it is in the drop down box, it has a db key as its option value for binding of this table with others in the database.

Comment: Follow up question - I have another page that could benefit from this functionality ... with the updatepanel approach, how would that work if there were 2 or more data bound drop down boxes that used the same table data.  How would update both of those drop down lists?  They are not "close" to eachother in the page so having one big updatepanel is not feasible unless it was the whole page.

Comment: In that case you'll probably just need to move the updatepanel out such that all elements you would want to update are inside of it.  A few alternatives come to mind, but they would be rather messy/hacky so I wouldn't want to try any of them unless there was a real problem with such a large updatepanel.